# Scrapy installation instructions unclear around registry mod

Tags: python, scrapy

I am installing Scrapy 0.22.2 into the Python 2.7 64 bit environment using Pip. I am following the instructions listed [here](http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7) in the appropriate order. I have got as far as exporting the Python 2.7 registry to a .txt file and amending the content. Then however it says

'Navigate to where you saved said file and double click on it to initiate a Registry Modification'. Is that a typo? All double clicking on a text file does it open it.

Apologies if this seems a dumb thing to ask, but I have never done any registry modifying before.

The instructions on how to install Scrapy vary from site to site. I have tried installing the latest version of Scrapy from PYPI using pip after i have installed twisted and zope, but received the following error message:

```
Removing temporary dir c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Oleg Salenko...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\olegsa~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_Oleg Salenko\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-m1ttmc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Oleg Salenko\lxml
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\olegsa~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_Oleg Salenko\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-m1ttmc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\olegsa~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Oleg Salenko\lxml
```

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't done any registry modifying I highly recommend you be careful.

Comment: @Colourity it seems a fairly straight forward text replace step, however im not really sure why this is required for the installation of a python module.

Comment: You've tried doing only `pip install scrapy` and it didn't work?

Comment: @elias post amended to show error message received when installing scrapy via pip without any reg mods.

Comment: @user3045351 Sorry, I'm not able to help you with that, I don't have much experience installing Python modules on Windows. =/

Comment: Are you installing the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Python 2.7?

Comment: @Talvalin i have the 64 bit version of python 2.7 installed to which i am trying to install scrapy and all it's dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

Rename the `.txt` file to `.reg`, then try double-clicking it.

If you don't see the file extension on the end of the file, then you'll probably end-up renaming it to `exampleFile.reg.txt`, but it will look like `exampleFile.reg` because the `.txt` on the end will be hidden. To avoid this, [make sure Windows isn't hiding extensions of known file types](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-vista).

Alternatively, you can

1. hit the `start` button
2. search for `cmd` in the box at the bottom
3. right-click and choose `Run as Administrator`
4. in the terminal that pops up, type `regedit.exe C:\path\to\that\file.reg` and hit `<enter>`

Comment: i got the following error when following your instructions: ' Cannon import C:\filepath\python2.7.reg: The specified file is not a registry script. You can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor.'